# Permutations of given cycle type and rotation

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

Let $p=k_1+\dotsb+k_r$ and $m$ an integer. Consider the big rotation $\sigma:=(1\,\dotsb\,p)$. I want to find another permutation $\tau$ with the following two properties:

1. $\tau$ has exactly $r$ cycles with lengths $k_1,\dotsc,k_r$,
2. $\tau\circ\sigma$ has exactly $m$ cycles (counting trivial cycles).

Property (1) determines $\tau$ uniquely up to conjugation, but maybe there is still a chance to find the right $\tau$ …

Comment: Do you perhaps mean the permutations to be in $S_p$? If they are in $S_N$ with $N>2p+m$ it's clearly impossible as $\tau\sigma$ will have more than $m$ fixed points. But even in $S_p$ there are $m$ for which it is impossible, e.g $m=p$ (unless $r=1$.)

Comment: Oh! Yes, of course I want this. That $\tau$ has cycle type $(k_1,\dotsc,k_r)$, should include also the trivial cycles, so $\tau$ has to be an element of $\mathfrak{S}_p$. And furthermore, of course $m\le p$.

Comment: I don't think you can do it for $p=5=1+1+3$, $m=4$.

Comment: Yes … after some calculations, I saw that it’s only possible if $p$ and $m$ have the same parity. However, I think then it’s generally possible with cycles of the form $(1\,\dotsb\, k\,p\,\dotsb\,(k+1))$.